# postgresql execParams paramTypes meaning?

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to perform an insert (C++) using different datatypes using execParams, but it keeps saying that the insert is failing. I believe this is because It's interpreting all my datatypes as text because I've set paramTypes to NULL. The documentation says

> If parameters are used, they are
>   referred to in the command string as
>   $1, $2, etc.  nParams is the number of
>   parameters supplied; it is the length
>   of the arrays paramTypes[],
>   paramValues[], paramLengths[], and
>   paramFormats[]. (The array pointers
>   may be NULL when nParams is zero.)
>   paramTypes[] specifies, by OID, the
>   data types to be assigned to the
>   parameter symbols.

What exactly are these OID's? Are they constants defined to represent different datatypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the description of OID for postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-oid.html).
You can get a list of type names and OIDs by executing the following query:

```
SELECT typname, oid FROM pg_type;
```

Also check out [the documentation for all the columns in pg_type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/catalog-pg-type.html), just in case.